# Progress dialog not dismissing in async task

Tags: android

The progress dialog in AsyncTask does not dismiss, even though progressDialog.dismiss is run in onPostExecute().

I have tried implementing many answers to related questions on SO, with no success so far.

I am sure that I must be overlooking something very basic, but I am stuck.

Any pointers to an explanation and code snippet would be great, Thanks.

**Main**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    String result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        asyncTask task = new asyncTask("Loading ...", this);
        try {
            result = task.execute("Question").get();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**asyncTask**

```
public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String message;
    private Context context;

    public asyncTask(String msg, Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        message = msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.show(context, "", message, true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count = 100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           // waste time
        }
        return "Answer";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be some exception, if this is the case then post your logcat output.

Comment: @PareshMayani, no exceptions are thrown, logcat is clean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually your are doing :

```
progressDialog.show(context, "", message, true, false);
```

instead it should be like :

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", message, true, false);
```

You have to statically call show method and assign it to your `progressDialog`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem, yes 100% correct, I thank very much for that and your other advice regarding .get()

Comment: @Mike you are are welcome. you can also thanks by up voting my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Make this changes in  your `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try{
           if(progrssDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
           }  
    }
  catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
       progressDialog.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A common issue i have found is the Variable Scope.
Most times , the ProgressDialog will be defined inside a Method , which wont be accessable outside that method.

You need to Declare it like so ,

```
Public Class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: This is just to give a partial overview of the code.. Lemme know if you need the full source code

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
task.execute("Question").get();
```

with

```
task.execute("Question");
```

by calling `.get()` you forcing `main thread` to wait. It will/can hang your UI.

Comment: Though this is a good *comment*, it is *not* an answer to this question.

Comment: @Niek it is actually the problem. by calling `.get()` `onPostExecute` never be called!

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem this is right answer. but can u edit your code as `//show progressbar here task.execute("Question").get(); // dismiss here` instead of onPostExecute

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes but it will just solve his problem for now. But it is bad practice you know. so I just want to use `execute`. and utilize `AsyncTask` in better shape.

Comment: I have break pointed onPostExecute and dismiss definitely does get called. an I just tried result = task.execute("Question"); with no success.

Comment: @Mike use `task.execute("Question");` instead of `result = task.execute("Question");`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K asyncTask task = new asyncTask("Loading ...", this);
  try {
   task.execute("Question");
  } // still the same

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem I'm sorry, I was not aware of that. I can't undo my downvote unless you edit your answer a bit. So if you do, I will upvote.

Answer (score -3):

```
    progressDialog.dismiss();
```

put this in doInBackground() method before Return Statement.

Comment: Maybe I have kill it from the UI thread, but I don't know how to do that?